# Keydown event that records the users correct input and displays it in the box without erasing on the next keydown event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am making a variation of a hangman game. I have the random word generator give me a word in the phrase variable and then the passPhrase variable breaks it into an array. I want the keydown function to compare the key pressed to the array and record the string if it is correct in the HTML

which is grabbed by the secretWord variable. The problem I am having is that the string will show when pressed correctly but disappears on the next keydown event. I also have a HTML

tag to show missed guesses grabbed by the variable pastGuess. it is showing every keydown event.

```js
        let phrase = generate(1);
        let passPhrase = phrase[0].split('');

        

        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
        for (let i=0; i < passPhrase.length; i++){
            if (event.key === passPhrase[i]) {
                secretWord.textContent = passPhrase[i];
                
                
            } else if (event.key != passPhrase[i]) {
                pastGuess.textContent = event.key;
            }
            
        }
        
        });
```

I am not sure why the if / else statement isnt preventing correct guesses from showing up in the pastGuess variable. I also have no clue how to go about getting the correct guesses to stay visible

Answer (score 0):

Try manually tracing through the execution of your for loop. If `event.key` is one of the letters in `passPhrase`, then on one of the iterations, `event.key` will equal `passPhrase[i]` and `secretWord` will get set to the letter. But on every other iteration, `event.key != passPhrase[i]`, so the else statement will set `pastGuess` to the same letter. EDIT: This is why `pastGuess` shows every key you press, even when the letter is correct and shouldn't show up. Try to think of how to change the loop and the if/else to not do this. Maybe don't set `secretWord` or `pastGuess` until you've finished looping so you can decide which one to modify.

When you say `secretWord` "disappears" on the next keydown, do you mean that if you press an incorrect letter, the text in `secretWord` fully disappears? Or that if you press another correct letter, the text in `secretWord` gets replaced with the new letter? In `secretWord.textContent = passPhrase[i]`, you are setting the whole content of the element to only the new letter, not adding the new letter to existing content.

EDIT:

Just setting `htmlElement.textContent = ...` will reset the whole contents of the element. Since you want to add to what's already there, it's probably best to keep track of everything purely in JS (in an array/object/etc; this is called your *state*), then whenever anything changes, update the HTML (more accurately, the DOM) accordingly in a function you might call *render*.

You basically have to remember which letters have been guessed yet and which ones haven't. You could try using [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) at the start to make `passPhrase` be an array of objects, each one looking like `{ letter: 'a', guessed: false }`. On each keydown, set each matching object in passPhrase to have `passPhrase[i].guessed = true`. Then call `render` whenever you change your state.

`render` can use `array.map` to turn each object into a string: either the letter if it has been revealed by the user, or a placeholder if it has not been guessed yet. Then use `join` to turn that into one string to put in a DOM element.

To display every new incorrect guess in addition to the old ones, you'll have to keep another piece of state: an array of past incorrect guesses. Similarly in `render`, map or join that into text to put in a DOM element.

Comment: if you hit a correct letter the new letter stays. I am not sure how to manually trace through and then set secretWord to receive all the correct letters (very new to this)

Comment: Manually tracing through a loop means pretend you are the computer, and walk step by step through the code, keeping track of all the variable values on paper. Go line by line, then at the end of the loop increment `i` and start the loop again. My first paragraph explains what you should see when you do this. The second paragraph is to solve a different problem, and I was just starting by getting some clarification on what you meant.

Answer (score -1):

you are updating `secretWord.textContent` and `pastGuess.textContent` inside the loop for every character in the `passPhrase`. This caused correct guesses to overwrite each other, and incorrect guesses to be displayed on each key press.

```
let phrase = generate(1);
let passPhrase = phrase[0].split('');
let correctGuesses = ""; // Store correct guesses

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    let correctKeyPressed = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < passPhrase.length; i++) {
        if (event.key === passPhrase[i]) {
            correctGuesses += passPhrase[i]; // Add correct guess
            correctKeyPressed = true;
        }
    }

    if (correctKeyPressed) {
        secretWord.textContent = correctGuesses; // Update correct guesses
    } else {
        pastGuess.textContent += event.key; // Add missed guess
    }
});
```